# Help me make the sides and faces for some trapezohedrons (like a dice D10 or D14) with a circumsphere for EVERY desire

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, dice, polyhedra

The goal: Make the face for a 10-sided dice or a heptagonal trapezohedron with a circumsphere, using as input one side of a face or the radius of the sphere.

**Let us be on the same page:**
*Circumsphere*: Exist a sphere that touches every point of the polyhedron.
*Antiprism*:

> ...a polyhedron composed of two parallel direct copies (not mirror images) of an k-sided polygon, connected by an alternating band of 2k triangles...
> -Wikipedia

*A shape is the dual polyhedron of another*: A vertice of one is  transformed into a face of the other, and viceversa; but the edges stay in their place.
*Trapezohedron*: The dual polyhedron of an antiprism. The 2k faces of an k-gonal trapezohedron are the same and are kites (also called deltoids).

1.- The faces, as described earlier, are kites; with a long side LS and a short side SS. **What must be the angles for this kite to be used for my polyhedron?** *Indicate if you're answering for a pentagonal or heptagonal trapezoihedron*

2.- **Now let's think I have the lenght of one side of the deltiod, How do I calculate the other so the kite can be a face of a trapezohedron with a circumsphere?** *Use l10(SS) and s10(LS) to answer this question with functions for a dice D10 or l14(SS) and s14(LS) for a heptagonal one.*

2.- Now, let's imagine I have a limited space for a cube box with side 2R, and I'd like my D10 or D14 to fit in there, so **the trapezohedron's circumsphere's radius must be R, but I don't know the sides of the faces** LS and SS, **I only know R. How do I calculate the sides of the deltoid only knowing R?** *Use L10(R) and S10(R) for the 10-sided dice and L14(R) and S14(R) for the 14-sided polyhedron*

I really hope you can help for the customized heptagonal trapezohedron D14. English isn't my first language, I hope I wrote everything correctly.

PD: Don't confuse l14() and s14() with L14() and S14()

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1247227/uniform-polyhedron-with-500-congruent-right-kite-faces